Compute electrostatic potential along z direction with dipoles?
There is a system that is full of particles. Each particle has a permanent dipole. (refer to AMOEBA force field) Suppose each particle has no charge and only one permanent dipole. The particle density $\rho(z)$ only changes in the z direction. I want to compute potential $\varphi(z)$  at any $z$ with the dipoles. The known conditions are the coordinate $z_i$, dipole $\mathbf{p}_i$ of each particle, and particle density $\rho(z)$.
This question is similar to the one that uses charge density to solve Poisson equation, the difference is here use dipoles or dipole density.
I have read two paper, paper that use the function
$$\varphi(z)=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0} \int P(z)\mathrm{d} z$$
to compute the potential, where $P(z)=\rho(z)\mu_z(z)$. $\rho(z)$ is the average local density of particles, and $\mu_z(z)$ should be the z component of the dipole moment in $dz$.
The following picture exhibits the details of the equation in the Supporting Information of the paper.

However, I am unsure if the function is suitable for my system. If it is suitable, then how to determine the limits of integration?
